# PHP exec() to open VS Code

Tags: php, macos, apache, visual-studio-code

It is possible to open a directory in Visual Studio Code using this terminal command:

```
code /path/to/directory
```

Now I want to open a directory in VS Code using PHP exec(). This doesn't work however. I also tried the PHP function system(); it returns "sh: code: command not found".

How do I open VS Code using PHP?

Comment: Why would you want to? PHP runs exclusively on the server, so unless you're running the PHP on the same system as the user, it won't work.

Comment: Type `which code` in your Terminal to get the full path to `code` and use that for calling the command, ie `/usr/local/bin/code /path/to/directory`

Comment: @cOle2 supplying PHP `system()` with the full path to code throws an error: `sh: usr/local/bin/code: No such file or directory` even though this is the full path returned by Terminal `which code`.

@aynber this is supposed to work on my local development machine - I have a webpage with all local sites listed and want to be able to open them in VS Code from this webpage